# expire the http request after 5 secs of call

Tags: php, android

I would like the make the http request expire after 5 secs in android .I am using php-mysql framework and using the code below to display images,artists with respect to the user.
The code below is working perfectly fine but its not secured .How to secure it? Please tell me how I can achieve it.

Thanks in Advance.

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://example.com/getmsgs/strno=123";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL);


        try {
            JSONObject arr2 = json.getJSONObject("feed");
            JSONArray arr = arr2.getJSONArray("entry");

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject e1 = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONArray arr3 = e1.getJSONArray("im:image");

                JSONObject arr8 = e1.getJSONObject("im:name");

                JSONObject arr10 = e1.getJSONObject("im:artist");

                    JSONObject e12 = arr3.getJSONObject(0);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,  e12.getString("label"));

            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, arr8.getString("label"));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, arr10.getString("label"));
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Network communication error!", 5).show();
        }


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(CustomizedListView.this, "ID '" + o.get("KEY_TITLE") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });     
    }   
}
```

PHP COde for the above request

```
    <?php

    $strno=$_GET['strno'];

    if (isset($strno))
    {
            $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","test","test") or die ('Connection error!!!');
            mysql_select_db("test") or die ('Database error!!!');

        $query=mysql_query("select sno FROM users  where strno='$strno';");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

        {
            $jsonoutput='{"json":{
                "image":"'.$row['image'].'",
"artist":"'.$row['artist'].'",
"name":"'.$row['name'].'"
                }}';
        }

    }

    echo trim($jsonoutput);
    mysql_close($connect) or die ('Unable to close connection-error!!!');
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: And? What happens when you run it?

Comment: what is the code of `getJSONfromURL` method? That's where you should fix it.

Comment: It executes perfectly but I would like to secure the entire request by encrypting something so that nobody can reuse the link again.Hence securing the request.

Comment: @Axarydax the code works perfectly fine .How do I secure it so that it cannot be reuse after 5 secs or by replicating the link in the browser.